# how to pass the sqlalchemyconnection string for oracle modin read_sql

Tags: oracle, modin, read-sql

```
UserWarning: To use parallel implementation of `read_sql`, pass the sqlalchemyconnection string instead of <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>.
```

I get gettign this error using this string

'oracle://username:password@server:1521/SID'

I also tried using cx_Oracle with the same error

I also tried passing the con string directly like :

```
OraTbl = pd.read_sql(colqry, 'oracle://username:password@{}:1521/SID'.format(server))
```

ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Comment: I also tried ``` oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@{}:1521/SID'.format(server)``` without success

Answer (score 0):

Track this issue [#3400](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/3400) to get answer to your question.